# How to extract the date string from a date object in PHP

Tags: php, laravel, date

I need to extract the date string from a  mysql `updated_at` date object. A `var_dump()` shows this:

```
 ["date"]=>
    object(Carbon\Carbon)#235 (3) {
      ["date"]=>
      string(26) "2016-04-26 16:41:05.000000"
      ["timezone_type"]=>
      int(3)
      ["timezone"]=>
      string(3) "UTC"
    }
```

My code looks like this:

```
$posts[] = array(
'id' => $post->id,
'text' => $post->text,
'category' => $category,
'image' => $post->image,
'date' => $post->updated_at
);
```

But after I've converted it to JSON, I end up with this:

```
"date":{"date":"2016-04-12 23:49:41.000000","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"UTC"}}
```

How do I get at that inner `date`?

Comment: you tagged as mysql but no code to support the question

Comment: $post is returned from a call that my Laravel framework maps to mysql. My question is really how to extract that date in PHP. Let me know if I've mis-tagged this and I'll change it,

Comment: if you feel that the mysql is irrelevant, it should be removed. Yet, if this does have a bearing on the query, then you may want to add the code for it. I have seen this happen before where people thought it was irrelevant, only to find out in the end (after too many comments) that the missing code was relevant to the question/problem; *just saying* ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since date it's still an object you've to assign the inner property like this:

```
 $posts[] = array(
'id' => $post->id,
'text' => $post->text,
'category' => $category,
'image' => $post->image,
'date' => $post->updated_at->date
);
```

Comment: I had tried that with this result: `InvalidArgumentException in Carbon.php line 527:
Unknown getter 'date'`

Comment: Thanks, Nicolo, to your help I got it working, though it turned our that I needed to require Carbon and add a print_r to utilise a side effect that enables access to the date properties.